# How to pass data to a non html template with yeoman generator

Tags: jenkins, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I want to pass the name of my project into a number of different files, none of which are html files.

Is it possible to do something like the example below for non html files?

```
writing: function() {
   // takes two arguments: sourcePath, destPath
   this.fs.copy('_someTpl', 'Jenkinsfile', {data: this.tplData});
}
```

Or is there a way to write the data to an html file and read the content of the html file within a Jenkinsfile? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeoman doesn't care what kind of file you're copying. For Yeoman, it's only text files.

I think your issue is using `copy` instead of `copyTpl`. Only `copyTpl` will inject the data in the template.